# How can I reload a custom module using r-box

Tags: r, r-box

I start to use the R package [box](https://klmr.me/box/index.html), but struggle during development of nested dependencies.

### Setup

Usually I develop a first function `helper.R`:

```
# helper.R
helper <- function(i) {
  return(paste("help", i))
}
```

Then a I use it in a wrapper:

```
# wrapper.R
box::use(./helper[helper])
lapply(1:3, helper)
```

Returning:

```
r$> lapply(1:3, helper)
[[1]]
[1] "help 1"

[[2]]
[1] "help 2"

[[3]]
[1] "help 3"
```

So far so good :-)

### Problem

Do not restart the R-session! Now, I change my helper:

```
# helper.R
helper <- function(i) {
  return(paste("Please help", i))
}
```

I would like to do `box::reload(./helper[helper])` or `box::reload("helper")` to use the update helper function, but I get this Error:

```
"reload" expects a module object, got "helper", which is not a module alias variable
```

I was expecting that `box::name()` would return this "module alias variable", but it does not :-( It returns `"helper"` which does not work with `box::reload()`.

I am clearly missing some terminology AND/OR syntax here? Can you please clarify how I can reload a local module without restarting the R session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box::reload` (and `box::unload`) expect a *module object* as their argument — not a name or path.

This means that the following works:

```
box::use(./helper)
lapply(1:3, helper$helper)

# …

box::reload(helper)
lapply(1:3, helper$helper)
# [[1]]
# [1] "please help 1"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "please help 2"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "please help 3"
```

However, ‘box’ does not support reloading attached names. As a workaround you can use the “nuclear” option for now:

```
box::purge_cache()
box::use(./helper[helper])
```

In the future, [‘box’ will implement hot code reloading](https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/234), which will make explicit calls to `box::reload` or `box::purge_cache` mostly unnecessary.

Comment: Great news about the "hot code reloading" looking forward to these changes :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

Reading the vignette carefully is always a good idea.

If you `box::use()` a function from a module directly, it is loaded into into the Attached Namespace that can be listed via `search()` (not via `ls()`):

```
r$> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "mod:./helper"      "tools:vscode"      "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"
[11] "org:r-lib"         "package:base"
```

Now, I can use this string to `detach()` the module from the Namespace, load the module again with the updated code:

```
r$> detach("mod:./helper")
r$> box::use(./helper[helper])
r$> lapply(1:3, helper)
[[1]]
[1] "Please help 1"

[[2]]
[1] "Please help 2"

[[3]]
[1] "Please help 3"
```

### Minimal code for reload

wrapper.R:

```
box::use(./helper)
lapply(1:3, helper$helper)
```

Now the whole module helper.R is loaded into the environment and can be listed with `ls()`:

```
r$> ls()
[1] "helper"
```

Now, `box::reload(helper)` can be called :-)

### Question

Is there a 1-liner to reload a single function from `box::use(./helper[helper])`?

Comment: Please note that your first code doesn’t actually work (and this is intentional), since the module is still cached even if you detach the attached environment. You will *not* get the output “please help” if you modified the code while R was running (you probably accidentally restarted R and edited the module’s code before initially loading it).

Comment: Also note that `detach("mod:./helper")` will stop working in the future, and you will get an error. The reason is that ‘box’ will change from creating a distinct attached environment per module to [a single `imports` environment](https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/178#issuecomment-970137400).